# "app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses" error when building on Android

Tags: android, react-native, build-error, react-native-vision-camera

I updated react-native-vision-camera from version 2.15.6 to 3.5.1. However, when I attempt to build the app, I encounter the following error, along with numerous duplicate class errors:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class com.facebook.debug.debugoverlay.model.DebugOverlayTag found in modules jetified-react-android-0.73.0-rc-debug.3-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-android:0.73.0-rc.3) and jetified-react-native-0.70-debug.5-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.70.5)
     Duplicate class com.facebook.debug.holder.NoopPrinter found in modules jetified-react-android-0.73.0-rc-debug.3-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-android:0.73.0-rc.3) and jetified-react-native-0.70-debug.5-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.70.5)
     Duplicate class com.facebook.debug.holder.Printer found in modules jetified-react-android-0.73.0-rc-debug.3-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-android:0.73.0-rc.3) and jetified-react-native-0.70-debug.5-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.70.5)
     Duplicate class com.facebook.debug.holder.PrinterHolder found in modules jetified-react-android-0.73.0-rc-debug.3-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-android:0.73.0-rc.3) and jetified-react-native-0.70-debug.5-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.70.5)
     Duplicate class com.facebook.debug.tags.ReactDebugOverlayTags found in modules jetified-react-android-0.73.0-rc-debug.3-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-android:0.73.0-rc.3) and jetified-react-native-0.70-debug.5-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.70.5)
     Duplicate class com.facebook.fbreact.specs.NativeAccessibilityInfoSpec found in modules jetified-react-android-0.73.0-rc-debug.3-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-android:0.73.0-rc.3) and jetified-react-native-0.70-debug.5-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.70.5)
     Duplicate class com.facebook.fbreact.specs.NativeAccessibilityManagerSpec found in modules jetified-react-android-0.73.0-rc-debug.3-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-android:0.73.0-rc.3) and jetified-react-native-0.70-debug.5-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.70.5)
     Duplicate class com.facebook.fbreact.specs.NativeActionSheetManagerSpec found in modules jetified-react-android-0.73.0-rc-debug.3-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-android:0.73.0-rc.3) and jetified-react-native-0.70-debug.5-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.70.5)
```

I'm currently using React Native version 0.70.5, and I'm unsure where the 0.73.0-rc3 comes from, except that it appeared after I installed version 3 of the react-native-vision-camera module.

I recall encountering issues with my previous version of React Native when version 0.71.0 was uploaded to Maven Central. To resolve the problem, I had to update my React Native version to one of their patch versions because my app started pulling the latest version of React Native from Maven Central. This information may be relevant to the current issue.

I've tried cleaning and rebuilding everything.